# Overloaded Template Classes

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working on a property-like system in c++, one component of which in an accessor template class, which creates static functions I can then pass pointers of, into my property class for get an set operations.

Here's what the accessor looks like:

```
template <typename T, typename V, V (T::*getf)(), void (T::*setf)(V)>
struct Accessor
{
    static V Get(T* obj)
    {
        return (obj->*getf)();
    }

    static void Set(T* obj, V aValue)
    {
        return (obj->*setf)(aValue);
    }
};
```

And a test class that I'll be using the accessor on. Note how SetFoo takes an int, where SetBar takes a const int&.

```
class TargetClass
{
    int foo;
    int bar;

public:
    TargetClass(int f, int b)
        : foo(f)
        , bar(b)
    {
    }

    int GetFoo()
    {
        return foo;
    }

    void SetFoo(int f)
    {
        foo = f;
    }

    int GetBar()
    {
        return bar;
    }

    void SetBar(const int& b)
    {
        bar = b;
    }
};
```

And finally, here's the usage:

```
int main()
{
    TargetClass* target = new TargetClass(5, 3);

    // Works great
    typedef Accessor<TargetClass, int, &TargetClass::GetFoo, &TargetClass::SetFoo> fooAcessor;
    fooAcessor::Set(target, 13);
    int foo = fooAcessor::Get(target);

    // Doesn't work, because TargetClass::SetBar takes a const int& as an argument, instead of an int
    typedef Accessor<TargetClass, int, &TargetClass::GetBar, &TargetClass::SetBar> barAcessor;

    delete target;
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried "overloading" the Acessor struct so it's 4th argument is a const V&, but that doesn't seem to work. Is what I'm trying to do here possible?

Comment: Why not consistently use `const int&` for the set functions? So then you change to `void SetFoo(int f)` and `template <typename T, typename V, V(T::*getf)(), void (T::*setf)(const V&)>`?

Comment: I'm trying to have the accessor be as flexible as possible. In practice, it will be used with not only primitive types, but also classes/structs, and pointers. Unfortunately it's not realistic to have the entire codebase use const references in all setters :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to c++17, and assuming that the proposed standard doesn't change in the meantime, you can have the types deduced automatically:

```
template <typename F>
struct get_types;

template <typename T, typename V, typename... VP>
struct get_types<V(T::*)(VP...)>
{
    using return_type = V;
    using class_type = T;
};

template <auto getf, auto setf>
struct Accessor {
    using V = typename get_types<decltype(getf)>::return_type;
    using T = typename get_types<decltype(getf)>::class_type;
    static V Get(T* obj)
    {
        return (obj->*getf)();
    }

    static void Set(T* obj, V aValue)
    {
        return (obj->*setf)(aValue);
    }
};

class TargetClass {
    int foo;
    int bar;
public:
    TargetClass(int f, int b)
        : foo(f)
        , bar(b) {}
    int GetFoo() { return foo; }
    void SetFoo(int f) { foo = f; }
    int GetBar() { return bar; }
    void SetBar(const int& b) { bar = b; }
};

int main()
{
    TargetClass* target = new TargetClass(5, 3);
    using fooAccessor = Accessor<&TargetClass::GetFoo, &TargetClass::SetFoo>;

    fooAccessor::Set(target, 13);
    int foo = fooAccessor::Get(target);

    using barAcessor = Accessor<&TargetClass::GetBar, &TargetClass::SetBar>;
    barAcessor::Set(target, 13);
    int bar = barAcessor::Get(target);

    delete target;
    return foo + bar;
}
```

As of this writing the program above [compiles on gcc 7 (snapshot)](https://godbolt.org/g/JmIWLC).

Comment: I don't currently have access to c++17, but good to know this will be supported at sometime in the future! (I had previously tried auto in the template parameter, only for the compiler to say that wasn't allowed.)

Comment: Also, nice trick getting the class and return types from the get and set functions!

Answer (score 1):

You could add another template parameter for the set function's parameter:

```
template <typename T, typename V, typename VP, V(T::*getf)(), void (T::*setf)(VP)>
```

And then use for both cases:

```
typedef Accessor<TargetClass, int, int, 
    &TargetClass::GetFoo, &TargetClass::SetFoo> fooAcessor;

typedef Accessor<TargetClass, int, const int&, 
    &TargetClass::GetBar, &TargetClass::SetBar> barAcessor;
```

Full program:

```
template <typename T, typename V, typename VP, V(T::*getf)(), void (T::*setf)(VP)>
struct Accessor
{
    static V Get(T* obj)
    {
        return (obj->*getf)();
    }

    static void Set(T* obj, V aValue)
    {
        return (obj->*setf)(aValue);
    }
};

class TargetClass
{
    int foo;
    int bar;

public:
    TargetClass(int f, int b)
        : foo(f)
        , bar(b)
    {
    }

    int GetFoo()
    {
        return foo;
    }

    void SetFoo(int f)
    {
        foo = f;
    }

    int GetBar()
    {
        return bar;
    }

    void SetBar(const int& b)
    {
        bar = b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    TargetClass* target = new TargetClass(5, 3);

    // now has extra int parameter
    typedef Accessor<TargetClass, int, int, &TargetClass::GetFoo, &TargetClass::SetFoo> fooAcessor;
    fooAcessor::Set(target, 13);
    int foo = fooAcessor::Get(target);

    // Works now, because TargetClass::SetBar's function parameter was specified explicitly as const int&
    typedef Accessor<TargetClass, int, const int&, &TargetClass::GetBar, &TargetClass::SetBar> barAcessor;
    barAcessor::Set(target, 13);
    int bar = barAcessor::Get(target);

    delete target;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to have it deduced automatically.