# Determine type from non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

I wish I could do this:

```
template <typename T x>
struct Test {
    T val{x};
};

int main() {
    Test<3> test;
    return test.val;
}
```

[But I can't. Right?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5628222/1460794)

---

I was answering a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41594595/1460794) and I use the following template:

```
template <typename T, typename V, typename VP, V(T::*getf)(), void (T::*setf)(VP)>
```

Each of the types are manually specified. But that is a duplication because `T`, `V` and `VP` are already contained in the pointers to member functions `getf` and `setf`'s types.

---

But if I try a template with only

```
template <V(T::*getf)(), void (T::*setf)(VP)>
```

or

```
template <V(T::*getf)(), void (T::*setf)(VP), typename T, typename V, typename VP>
```

then the types cannot be determined.

---

Next I tried specialization:

```
template <typename T, typename T2>
struct Accessor;

template <typename V, typename T, typename VP>
struct Accessor <V(T::*)(), void (T::*)(VP)>
```

which will determine all of the types if use

```
typedef Accessor<
    decltype(&TargetClass::GetFoo), 
    decltype(&TargetClass::SetFoo)> fooAcessor;
```

But now I don't have the pointers anymore, only the types.

---

Is there a way to write a template so that the types can be determined automatically from the non-type template parameter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way to write a template so that the types can be determined automatically from the non-type template parameter?

In C++17, yes, thanks to [declaring non-type template parameters with `auto`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html):

```
template <auto x>
struct Test {
    decltype(x) val{x};
};
```

Before C++17, no. You'd have to write:

```
template <class T, T x>
struct Test {
    T val{x};
};
```

Comment: @Quentin Ahem, [Westie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Highland_White_Terrier)!

Comment: Whoops. Busted cover is busted, I don't know a thing about dogs :( -- But hey, there's magic and there's C++, and it's a dog, that's like only 25% failure!